# Ruby error: `calcular_valor_final': undefined method `*'

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby and when I try to create a function a problem happened.

I have 4 files: vendas.rb, pagamento.rb, frete.rb and init.rb

frete.rb

```
module Frete
    TABELA_FRETE = {"BA": 1.95, "SP": 3.87, "PE": 2.59}

    def imprimir_tabela_frete
        puts "--- Tabela de Frete ---"

        TABELA_FRETE.each do |k,v|
            puts "#{k} - #{v}"           
        end
        puts "-------------------------"
    end

    def calcular_valor_final(valor_produto, uf)
        puts TABELA_FRETE[uf]
        valor_produto * TABELA_FRETE[uf]
    end
end
```

pagamento.rb

```
module Pagamento
    SIMBOLO_MOEDA = "R$"

    def pagar(valor_final)
        puts "Deseja pagar com cartão? (S/N)"
        opcao = gets.chomp.upcase

        if opcao == "S"
            puts "Pagando com cartão..."
        else
            puts "Pagando com dinhero..."
        end
    end

    class Pagseguro
        def initializer
            puts "Usando Pagseguro..."
        end
    end
end
```

venda.rb

```
require_relative "frete.rb"
require_relative "pagamento"

class Venda
    include Pagamento
    include Frete

    PRODUTOS = {"PS3": 900.00, "PS4": 1600.00}

    def imprimir_produtos
        puts "--- Produtos ---"

        PRODUTOS.each do |k,v|
            puts "#{k} - #{Pagamento::SIMBOLO_MOEDA} #{v}"
        end

        puts "--------------------"
    end
    
    def vender
        puts "Olá! Seja Bem-vindo!"
        puts "O que deseja comprar? "

        imprimir_produtos

        puts "> Digite o nome do produto... "
        produto = gets.chomp.upcase

        puts "> Para onde deseja enviar?"
        imprimir_tabela_frete

        puts "> Digite o estado... "
        uf = gets.chomp.upcase

        puts "Calculando... "

        valor_final = calcular_valor_final(PRODUTOS[produto], uf)

        puts "Você deve pagar #{Pagamento::SIMBOLO_MOEDA} #{valor_final} do produto + frete."
        puts "Deseja pagar? (S/N)"
        
        opcao = gets.chomp.upcase

        if opcao == "S"
            pagseguro = Pagamento::Pagseguro.new
            pagar(valor_final)
        else
            puts "Ok! Fica para a próxima! :("
        end
    end
end
```

init.rb

```
require_relative "venda"

v = Venda.new
v.vender
```

When I run init.rb my code should get the function "calcular_valor_final" and multiply "product" by the "freight value"

```
def calcular_valor_final(valor_produto, uf)
        valor_produto * TABELA_FRETE[uf]
    end
```

However, the error below is showned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from init.rb:4:in `<main>'
        1: from /mnt/d/Credere/Treinamento_Ruby/aula19/venda.rb:37:in `vender'
/mnt/d/Credere/Treinamento_Ruby/aula19/frete.rb:15:in `calcular_valor_final': undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I can't find on the web some errors like this!

Someone may help me to show me why this error occurs, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error:

```
undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass
```

means that the object you're trying to call the `*` method on is **`nil`**, and therefore it's not possible, because no such method exists for `NilClass`. (You can multiply a number by something, but it makes no sense to "multiply `nil` by something"!)

In other words, in your scenario, it means that `valor_produto == nil`.

Which means that `PRODUTOS[produto]` must be `nil`.

And this is happening because you've defined `PRODUCTOS` like this:

```
PRODUTOS = {"PS3": 900.00, "PS4": 1600.00}
```

Which is equivalent to defining it like this:

```
PRODUTOS = {:PS3 => 900.00, :PS4 => 1600.00}
```

...where the hash keys are **`Symbol`s**, *not `String`s*.

In ruby, a [`Symbol`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html) and a [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html) are different objects:

```
"this" != :this
```

...Because `"this"` is a `String`, and `:this` is a `Symbol`.

tl;dr: What you intended to do was either define the constant like this instead:

```
PRODUTOS = {"PS3" => 900.00, "PS4" => 1600.00}
```

Or, alternatively, convert the user input into a `Symbol`:

```
produto = gets.chomp.upcase.to_sym
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Very complete answer.